# Python code to connect to MySQL database doesn't work on Google Colab

Tags: python, mysql, google-colaboratory

I wrote the code bellow. It works on a `.py` file on my computer but not while running on Google Colab)

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector as msql
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
    conn = msql.connect(host='localhost',database='transport_db_hl' ,user='root',  
                        password='******')#give ur username, password
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL now ", e)
```

My server status is like that:

[image]

Comment: The Colab notebook runs on a different machine somewhere in one of Google's data centres. This means localhost is not correct as the location of the database. Instead you will have to expose your MySQL instance on the public Internet so Colab can find it. This will mean you will need to open up firewalls and forward port 3306 as well as get yourself an IP address or URL that can be seen by Colab.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make:

1. your mysql server publicly available (hint: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-remote-connection)
2. presumably enable port forwarding on your router (hint: https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/)
3. find your public IP (hint: https://www.whatsmyip.org/)
4. and replace the "localhost" with your public IP in your code above